# Control website maintenance page through web.cofig

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

We have an IIS server that hosts hundreds of web applications. During maintenance time, I want to redirect to the maintenance page. To do this instead of adding app_offline.htm to all the applications I want to create a single maintenance.html page and set a flag to turn on/off in web.config file to redirect to that maintenance page wherever it is.

I tried the below approach but not working.

**maintenance.html**

```css
  body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; }
  h1 { font-size: 50px; }
  body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }
  article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px;                  margin: 0 auto; }
  a { color: #dc8100; text-decoration: none; }
  a:hover { color: #333; text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>Site Maintenance</title>
<article>
    <h1>We&rsquo;ll be back soon!</h1>
      <div>
          <p>Sorry for the inconvenience but we&rsquo;re performing some maintenance at the moment. If you need to you can always <a href="mailto:#">contact us</a>, otherwise we&rsquo;ll be back online shortly!</p>
        <p>&mdash; The Team</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

**web.config**

```
  <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="SiteDown" stopProcessing="true">
     <action type="Redirect" url="/maintenance.html" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: `app_offline.htm` is specially treated by IIS/ASP.NET, while your own page does not. That's not something you can clone via simple URL rewriting, so don't waste your time.

Comment: other than app_offline are there any other ways?